# Concatenating similar items in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a list of similar and unique words. The similar words are appeared in one string and are separated by "|".

`input = ["car | cat", "cat | caat", "car | caar", "dog", "ant | ants"]`

I want to get the following output so that we could find out car, cat, caat, and caar are all similar instead of having pairs of similar words that have been repeated. So target output is like this:

`output= ["car | cat | caat | caar", "dog" , "ant | ants"]`

So far, I've managed to get ["car | cat | caat | caar", "dog", "ant", "ants"]. But I want to keep "ant | ants" intact since it doesn't have any word in common with any other pairs.

Is someone able to write a python code to solve this problem?

**Edit:**

Here is the code to my attempt but I don't want to make you feel that you should use the same approach.

```
def concat_common_words(input):
    my_list = input
    split_my_list = [x.split(" | ") for x in my_list]

    flat_my_list = [i for j in split_my_list for i in j]

    count_my_list = Counter(flat_my_list)

    common = [k for k, v in count_my_list.items() if v > 1]

    target_my_list = [x for x in my_list if any(c in x for c in common)]

    flat_target_my_list = set(sf for sfs in target_my_list for sf in sfs.split(" | "))

    merged = [" | ".join(flat_target_my_list)] \
    + list(set(flat_my_list) - flat_target_my_list) 

    return merged
concat_common_words(["car | cat", "cat | caat", "car | caar", "dog", "ant | ants"])
```

It returns  ["car | cat | caat | caar", "dog" , "ant" , "ants"]
. But as I mentioned, I ant to keep "ant | ants" intact.

Comment: define "similar". Then use lists of sets to describe your structures, not strings separated by the pipe character. Things will be much simpler

Comment: Imagine words that have Levenshtein distance of less than 8 are similar.

Comment: Is someone able to write a python code to solve this problem? probably, but less and less people will attempt that, because your problem is too broad and since you haven't attempted anything, answerers could miss your question completely.

Comment: So, do you have a function that computes the Levenshtein distance between two words?

Comment: Hey Jean, I edited the post and added my attempt. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# I would create a set() for each group e.g. car | cat
# when adding a new group I would then merge with any existing group if
# they intersect.

data = ["car | cat", "cat | caat", "car | caar", "dog", "ant | ants"]


groups = []
for item in data:
    words = set(item.split(" | "))
    to_remove = []
    for existing_group in groups:
        if words.intersection(existing_group):
            words.update(existing_group)
            to_remove.append(existing_group)
    for removal in to_remove:
        groups.remove(removal)
    groups.append(words)

# convert groups back to pipe separated
final_groups = [" | ".join(group) for group in groups]
```

Comment: Thanks @y_e I have updated to fix this and more cases.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work as expected with this example  ["car | caar", "cat | caat", "car | cat"] so I had to use this code twice like func(func(data)), but it worked in the end!

Comment: Yeah - the fix above still left a lot to be desired - sorry @y_e - I have again fixed. I had accidentally modified the list as i was looping on it which isn't great practise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Levenshtein distance, proceed as follows:

```
from Levenshtein import distance as lev

data = ["car | cat", "cat | caat", "car | caar", "dog", "ant | ants"]

# set the desired threshold
threshold = 1

# create a unique set of trimmed strings
dataset = set([e.strip() for ls in [ s.split('|') for s in data ] for e in ls ])

# create a list of dicts to check already take strings
dl = [ { 'name': s, 'taken': False } for s in dataset ]

dd = []

for i in range(0, len(dl)):
    # check whether it is not taken
    if dl[i]['taken'] is False:
        ds = set()
        dl[i]['taken'] = True
        ds.add(dl[i]['name'])
        for j in range(i + 1, len(dl)):
            # check whether it is not taken and satisfying distance
            if dl[j]['taken'] is False and lev(dl[i]['name'], dl[j]['name']) <= threshold:
                dl[j]['taken'] = True
                ds.add(dl[j]['name'])
        dd.append(' | '.join(ds))
    
print(dd)

# output: ['caar | cat | caat', 'caar | car', 'car', 'ant | ants']
```